# Click sound when I pedal hard

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, chain, crankset

I have click sound when I do pedal hard and uphill.

I tried to troubleshoot:

- Tighten my pedal.
- Tighten my crank.

and I tried to remove my chain on and tried to add force to left pedal and it clicks, again I tried to add force on the right and it clicks. ( but when I add force on same location it wont click after it clicks).

I assume the problem is within the crank.

Anyone can help me? I also tried to go on mechanic but they said it was on my cogs.

Comment: sounds to me like it's your bottom bracket

Comment: Mine sounded similar when the ball bearing in the pedal was failing. You can check this by spinning the pedal on its hub. If it stops quickly or is making that noise, the bearings are going bad.

Comment: Try dropping the chain off the chainrings and see if you can replicate the sound.  You need to figure out where its coming from.

Comment: Does it also happen out of the saddle? Try to swap your pedals for some other pair for diagnostics.

Comment: @Criggie I tried that one and still i have the same problem.

Comment: @VladimirF I tried the saddle but still I have the same issue, I also stand on the pedal alternatively and still clicks.

Comment: @CarlvicJapitanaLim Good - if you're testing out of the saddle, then that proves the click is pedals, crank, or bottom bracket.   Keep searching for the cause - it will feel like some play, somewhere that shouldn't have play.

Comment: Would help to know something about the bike.  I've had clicks like this when the cartridge in my bottom bracket was loose, but we don't know if you have the style with a cartridge.

Answer (score 1):

It could be from a bad chain, bent chainring/sprocket, worn out cassette or freewheel, incorrect installation of chainring/bolts, bent tooth, missing spacer in the bottom bracket/cranks, bent crank arm, etc etc.

Have you inspected every single tooth on your sprocket to see if any of them are bent?  A bent tooth might cause a clicking sound.

Does your chain have even slack or does it fluctuate from more to less slack as you pedal?
If this is the case, you can fix the slack issue by tightening the chainring bolts in the correct way.

Is your chain clean and lubed?

A chain line issue could be causing the problem.  If any of the parts on your bike have ever been changed/upgraded, there's a good chance the size of the part was slightly off causing the chain to not be in perfect alignment.

Flip your bike upside down and look where the sprocket teeth are coming up through the chain. Are the teeth perfectly centered in the chain or does it favor one side of the gap?

If it's uneven, you can try using a bottom bracket spacer/washer to center the chain line.

Your bottom bracket/bearings might need to be checked out.  I once had a sealed bearing cartridge that was too old and used to make a popping/cracking sound every few pedal rotations.  Replacing it fixed the problem.

If it's none of these, try swapping out different parts and you'll locate the problem pretty fast.  Start with a part you were planning to upgrade or replace soon anyway or whatever's easiest/cheapest.